# Finding the square root of a number using bisection method

Tags: python, bisection

I have tried to find the square root of a number such that

```
 abs(y**2-x) < epsilon
```

using the bisection method, however, I don't get the answer I want when I run it. If I choose x to be 4 and 0.01, I expect to get 2, but instead, I get 1.0. Can anyone please help me fix this?

Test Case:

```
 > squareRoot(4, 0.01)
 > 1.0
```

```py
def squareRoot(x, epsilon):
    low = 0
    high = max(1.0, x)
    y = (high+low) / 2.0
    while abs(y**2 - x)<epsilon:
        if y**2 < x:
            low = y
        else:
            high = y
        y = (high + low) / 2.0
    return y
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I think your `while` condition is wrong.

Comment: But abs(y**2-x) has to be less than epsilon, though

Comment: Sure, but you're supposed to **return** when `abs(y**2-x)` is less than epsilon. You're not supposed to keep going through the while loop and modifying the answer.

Comment: Did you mean `while abs(y**2-x) > epsilon:`???

Answer (score 6):

Your `while` condition has the inequality flipped. You're only modifying `y` in the event that you've already found a good enough answer. In pseudocode, you want to do the following.

```
def squareRoot(x, epsilon):
  <set up the base case>
  while <you haven't found the answer yet>:
    <bisect to keep looking for the answer>
  return <the answer>
```

Compare that to what your code currently does.

```
def squareRoot(x, epsilon):
  <set up the base case>
  while <you have found the answer>:
    <bisect to keep looking for the answer>
  return <the answer>
```

A one-character modification of your code that gives the correct solution is then the following.

```
def squareRoot(x,epsilon):
    low = 0
    high = max(1.0,x)
    y = (high+low)/2.0
    while abs(y**2-x)>=epsilon:
        if y**2 < x:
            low = y
        else:
            high = y
        y = (high+low)/2.0
    return y
```

Comment: But I have to find y such that abs(y**2-x) has to be less than epsilon, though

Comment: You need to keep looping `while` it is `>= epsilon`... and stop looping when this expression is `False`.

Comment: wait so where do I show the abs(y**2) < epsilon condition?

Comment: When `abs(y**2-x) >= epsilon` is `False` it means that `abs(y**2-x) < epsilon` - you can stop looping and return the result. `while` loops execute when the condition is `True` and exits when the condition is `False`.

Comment: @Hans Musgrave I get the modification, but I'm still confused there the abs(y**2) < epsilon condition goes

Comment: @deezy you can use `not (abs(y**2) < epsilon)` if you insist.

Comment: Wait but it says I need to find a square root such that  the square root of a number such that

 abs(y**2-x) < epsilon

Comment: @deezy and the code in the answer does that. Think of the relationship of `>=` and `<`.